# Setting wxTE_PASSWORD later

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I created two wxTextCtrl. One for log in (loginTxt) and another for password (pwdTxt) and both have readable default message.

I also installed wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN event so that when user click on either loginTxt or pwdTxt the default message will be set to empty string

Is it possible to set wxTE_PASSWORD style to the pwdTxt later? If it's possible, how can I do that?

I read wx.chm and it say,

"Note that alignment styles (wxTE_LEFT, wxTE_CENTRE and wxTE_RIGHT) can be changed dynamically after control creation on wxMSW and wxGTK. wxTE_READONLY, wxTE_PASSWORD and wrapping styles can be dynamically changed under wxGTK but not wxMSW. The other styles can be only set during control creation.".

I am writing my application on MS Windows with wxWidgets 2.9.3

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change it later on Windows, since Microsoft's control does not support that. If you really need to, I suggest creating 2 different controls and show/hide the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Windows-only solution, probably will be useful:

```
void Sample::OnBUTTONClick( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)m_Text->GetHandle();
    SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, 0x25cf, 0); // 0x25cf is ● character
    m_Text->Update();
#endif
}
```